# How to apply scaler module with groupby in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I want to scale one column in my dataframe. However, I have different groups within my dataframe. I want to scale within a group. How would I do this? Currently, my code scaled the column in relation to all rows but again, I want this done within a group.

```
group | price 
A     | 10
A     | 0.1
B     | 1203
B     | 999
```

I want the scaler to apply individually for row 1-2 and 3-4 in this case. This is where my code is:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler()    
df[['price']] = scaler.fit_transform(df[['price']])
```

Problem with this code: It scales using the entire price column instead of doing this by group.

Please advise!

Comment: What is `scaler`? Anyway you can try groupby and apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this, where I have used a sample function `foo` (instead of `scaler.fit_transform`) that modifies a pandas Series based on the data it contains:

```py
import pandas as pd
def foo(ser):
    x = ser.mean()
    return ser - x

df = pd.DataFrame({
'group':['A','A','B','B'],
'price':[10,0.1,1203,999]})
print(df)

df[['price']] = foo(df[['price']])
print(df)

df[['price']] = df.groupby('group')[['price']].apply(foo)
print(df)
```

Input:

```
  group   price
0     A    10.0
1     A     0.1
2     B  1203.0
3     B   999.0
```

Output if applied to entire `price` column (*not* what you want):

```
  group    price
0     A -543.025
1     A -552.925
2     B  649.975
3     B  445.975
```

Output if applied group-by-group:

```
  group   price
0     A    4.95
1     A   -4.95
2     B  102.00
3     B -102.00
```

If you replace `foo` with `scaler.fit_transform` in the above code, it should do what you want.